# Python - return to the start of a function if an invalid input is made?

Tags: python, int

I'm trying to catch an input error - where the only valid input is an integer.

If a non integer is input, I want it to return to the start of func and try again:

```
def setItorator():
 try:
  iterationCap = int(raw_input("Please enter the number of nibbles you want to make: "))
  print "You will make", iterationCap, "nibbles per file"
 except ValueError:
  print "You did not enter a valid integer, please try again"
  setItorator()
 return iterationCap 

if __name__ == "__main__":
 iterationCap = setItorator()
```

This method works if the first input is valid, and returns to the start of the func if a non valid input is made, but it does not seem to pass the correct valid back to the main func. I checked in the sub func that it sees the correct variable, and of the correct type (int) and it does appear to, but I get an error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'iterationCap' referenced before assignment
```

I do not see this error if the first input is valid (e.g. "10") only if the first input is not valid (e.g. "a" followed by "10")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
while True:
   try:
    i = int(raw_input("Enter value "))
    break
   except ValueError:
    print "Bad input"

print "Value is ",i
```

Your current approach will recursively call your function for every error which is not a good practice. The error is because inside your exception handler block, you're not defining `iterationCap`.

Comment: Oh, cool, thank you. I will have a play with this approach. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is a good advice. No need for recursion, just use loops.

Comment: I'm on board. This was very quick to implement, and I can see the value in holding this in a loop rather than my recursive approach. Thanks again all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return setItorator()` in the except statement. Right now, you're just calling the function and ignoring the output.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you. I didn't realise you could 'point' the return statement in that way. Appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. After a few hundred/thousand recursions you might get a `RuntimeError:  maximum recursion depth exceeded` (it's because a function is calling itself too many times, and it may go into an infinite loop). But this is not a problem for you here I guess :D